# Index of an array from a 2d np.array in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, indexing, 2d

i have a problem with find a index from a 2d `np.array()`. With an If-loop the computing time is too high for my algorithm. I need a numpy func to find the index from any array. The function `np.where()` doesn’t help me.. This is an abstraction:

```
>>> conditions = [[0 0 0 0 4]
[0 0 0 0 3]
[0 0 0 0 2]
..., 
[2 1 3 4 2]
[2 1 3 4 1]
[2 1 3 4 0]]
>>> a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
>>> index = np.where(conditions==a)
```

If I use it so, although I have the column and row indices, but I can not interpret them. I need the concrete index value, for example `index = 2`.

Comment: Please create a minimal demonstrative code. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> np.where((conditions ==  a).all(axis=1))[0]
array([2])
```